# Can the C# DateTime.TryParse be made to require a day, month and year?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using `DateTime.TryParse` to parse a Date of Birth which is captured from a Chatbot. Because of the conversational nature of the Chatbot, users may enter their DOB in a variety of formats, such as "jun 5 1980" or "3/21/1974". In this sense, `DateTime.TryParse` is perfect, because it can parse these and other formats just fine.

However, if you provide a partial date, such as "10/24" or "June 1977", the `TryParse` will succeed, and the missing date component will be defaulted. For a DOB, this is not ideal, as we don't want to accept an incomplete date. Is there any way to prevent this defaulting and tell the parser to only succeed at parsing a date which defines all three of the day, month and year?

Comment: Use `TryParseExact`?

Comment: But `TryParseExact` requires specifying one specific format, right? I ideally want to still retain the ability to match any of the formats which contains a day, month and year.

Comment: You would have to specify multiple formats with multiple uses of TryParseExact.

Comment: Is 6-5-1980 june 5th or may 6th?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would work but would certainly be a bit verbose. If there's no other way, though, that may be what we'll have to do.

Comment: @jasen - depends on the locale of the person typing into the chat

Comment: @jasen, our users will all be in the US, so we would assume it's June 5th.

Comment: Defaulted year should be easy to check for, too... TryParse defaults to the current year, so unless your user is < 1 year old... Only other case is defaulted day-of-month (1), which is a little harder to check for; doesn't seem like TryParse ever tries to interpolate month without all 3 components specified.

Comment: @Dusty yeah, if it were just year we'd have no problem, but I can't figure out a way to infer that the day was defaulted. Alas, might have to just do a ton of `TryParseExact`!

Comment: @SamHanley no need for a ton of TryParseExact.  There's an overload that accepts many formats.  See my answer.

Comment: Would you be willing to use an extension method on strings?

Comment: Since you are writing a chatbot, you should probably look to a library that provides Natural Language Processing (NLP).  There are many, and some have date/time specific functionality.  What you ask about here is just one of many edge cases you will encounter if you try to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TryParseExact with multiple formats.  It may get a little tedious having to list each format you want, but this way you're being explicit about it.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)

The following code is a simple, contrived example using two formats.  I'm using the en-US culture, but you can substitute your own culture (or an invariant culture) as needed.

```
DateTime dt;
var str = "6/5/2007";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MM/DD/YYYY", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
    || DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MM/DD/YY", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
{

}
```

OR

You can use the second overload for `DateTime.TryParseExact`.  The following code is equivalent to the first code example:

```
DateTime dt;
var str = "6/5/2007";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, new[] { "MM/DD/YYYY", "MM/DD/YY" }, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{

}
```

Comment: I think I missed an argument in calling `TryParseExact` but you get the idea.  I typed the code in Notepad++ instead of a C# editor :(

Comment: That's definitely more appealing than a laundry list of repeated calls - thanks for the direction!

Comment: @SamHanley i present both because the downside to the second overload is each format uses the same style and culture, whereas the first lets you vary these per format.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried TryParseExact?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

Only drawback would be to list all the formats you expect...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that would likely work, but I was hoping there was some way around itemizing the entire list of every supported format for a day, month and year. This may turn out to be the best available option, though.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible... Another possibility: you parse the date with TryParse, and then, with say, a regex, you try to identify the day, month and year in the initial string. If one element is missing, inform the user that his birthdate was not correctly provided (and at the same time, informing him that he needs to provide day, month and year). Quite a lot of work thought, the regex (or should I say, regexS) would be pretty massives.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to use only `TryParse`: you compare the input string with the output you get. Basically, you check that the input string is contained in all formats available for the birthdate in the current culture.
Example:

```cs
string myDateOK = "01/12/17";
DateTime.TryParse(myDateOK, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime myDateAsDate1);
var isFullDate_myDateAsDate1 = false;

string myDateKO = "12/17";
DateTime.TryParse(myDateKO, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime myDateAsDate2);
var isFullDate_myDateAsDate2 = false;


if (myDateAsDate1.Date.GetDateTimeFormats(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Contains(myDateOK))
{
    isFullDate_myDateAsDate1 = true;
}

if (myDateAsDate2.Date.GetDateTimeFormats(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Contains(myDateKO))
{
    isFullDate_myDateAsDate2 = true;
}

// => isFullDate_myDateAsDate1 = true and isFullDate_myDateAsDate2 = false
```

Comment: You'd still have to add some kind of check for the year though: in "plain text", ergo "december 2", this method would return true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `TryParseExact()` and an extension method. Just list down all the formats you expect the user to enter as date once in a list, and call `TryParseExact()` on the list until you find a hit.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool StrictTryParse(this string s, out DateTime result)
    {
        result = DateTime.MinValue;

        // List all the formats you want here.
        // Could move this out of the method, or make it a parameter.
        List<string> formats = new List<string> { "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yy" };

        foreach (string format in formats)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This way you can call the extension method `StrictTryParse()` more or less the same way you would `TryParse()` but with the functionality you need.

```
string dateStr = "08/23/2017";
DateTime dt;
if (dateStr.StrictTryParse(out dt))
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}.", dt.ToLongDateString());
```